# Find control in RoleGroup of LoginView

Tags: asp.net, findcontrol, loginview

I have some textboxes and checkboxes inside a RoleGroup of a LoginView.  How can I access these controls in my code-behind?

```
<asp:LoginView ID="lgvAdmin" runat="server">
        <RoleGroups>
            <asp:RoleGroup Roles="Administrator">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <div class="floatL">
                        <h1>Administrator Settings</h1>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkActive" Text="Is Active" Checked="false" runat="server" /><br />                    
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkIsRep" Text="Is Representative" Checked="false" runat="server" />
                        <br /><br />
                        <strong>User Permissions</strong><br />
                        <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatColumns="3" Width="200" Font-Bold="true">
                            <asp:ListItem Value="User" Selected="True">User</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="Administrator">Administrator</asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:RadioButtonList><br /><br />
                    <strong>Assigned to Rep</strong><br />
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DDLRep" CssClass="ddlStyle" Width="165" runat="server" />
                </div>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:RoleGroup>
    </RoleGroups>
</asp:LoginView>
```

I know I need to use the FindControl method and I also know it isn't just lgbvAdmin.FindControl("chkIsRep")  because of the hierarchy of where the control is.

So, it should be something like, lgvAdmin.controls[0].FindControl("chkIsRep");

How can I find the exact path to access my control?

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old post but here is a quick sample on how to do this for anyone else who needs the answer:

```
ITemplate template = lgvAdmin.RoleGroups[0].ContentTemplate;
if (template != null)
{
    Control container = new Control();
    template.InstantiateIn(container);

    foreach (Control c in container.Controls)
    {
        if (c is CheckBox)
        {
            //Do work on checkbox
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for the right track!  Alternatively, `ITemplate template = lgvAdmin.RoleGroups[0].ContentTemplate.InstantiateIn(container)` To cut it down a tad.  If you don't know the roles to search, use LoginView.RoleGroups to find them.  If you know the index of the child control, after instantiating the ContentTemplate into a control container, you could also access it like so to avoid looping every control in the container.
    `CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)container.Controls[1];`

Answer (score 0):

if request is not authenticated the rolegroup template won't apply to page and can't be found there for use if block like below

```
if(Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
    CheckBox chkactive=(CheckBox)lgvAdmin.FindControl("chkActive");
    chkavtive.Checked=true;
}
```